# ARM Assembly First Stage Bootloading Concept

Tags: assembly, arm, bootloader, firmware

I'm going to write a first stage bootloader that will directly load the firmware into RAM from flash, using ARM Assembly on a Cortex A7 based processor.
I have a basic idea of how I could do it, but I'm not sure about it :

Before the firmware's very first instruction bytes in flash, there will be a word that indicates the total length of the firmware in bytes. This value will be loaded into, let's say, r1, which will act as a counter.

We're then gonna use two registers as pointers (let's say, r2 and r3)
r2 will initially be loaded with the address of the first bytes of firmware into flash. r3 will initially loaded with the address of the first free bytes of RAM where the firmware will be written. r4 will serve as temporary storage for the current instruction to be transferred.

We're now ready to transfer the firmware :

```
loadLoop:
    LDR r4, [r2] ;grab instruction from flash
    STR r4, [r3] ;write it to RAM
    ADD r2, #4 ;increment flash pointer by 32 bit
    ADD r3, #4 ;increment RAM pointer by 32 bits
    SUB r1, #4 ;decrement counter by 32 bits
    CMP r1, #0 ;did we load all of the firmware?
    BNE loadLoop ;if not, keep going
otherCode:
... ;firmware is now in place, init process can go on
```

I'm still a beginner and I know this might miss some steps but my question is, did I get the general concept right?

Comment: "did I get the general concept right?" - concept of what ? concept of a loop ? That loop should work, and could be half of size

Comment: All ARM-32 CPUs available have a post increment mode.  Ie, `ldr r4, [r2], #4`.  As well, the loop will be far faster if you do multiple bytes at a time.  Ie, use `ldrd` and `strd` or `ldm` and `stm`.  Enabling the cache may also be simple and will speed the boot process significantly.  Another optimization is to use the end address.  ie, `cmp r4,r5`, where r5 would be the end address (start + size).  You can expand/unroll the loop and subsequent load/stores be be conditional.  Your code is fine as is.  However, some or all of the above will dramatically decrease boot time.

Comment: Also, just look at `memcpy()` implementations.  By using linker scripts and requiring alignment, you can add additional optimizations over a standard `memcpy()` which has to cope with unaligned cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have the concept right, depending on which arm instruction set you can simplify this loop to be fewer instructions. (cortex-a7 you can combine 6 of the instructions into 3 leaving you with 4 instructions total for the loop, not exactly half...) And if you want performance there are other optimizations you can do.  But this appears functional.